# output of program is not same as passed argument

Tags: c++

Why I am getting different out put of both the width and height variable in below program

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class my_space {
    public :
        void set_data(int width,int height) // taking the same name of the variable as the class member functions
        {
            width = width;
            height = height;
        }
        int get_width()
        {
            return width;
        }
        int get_height()
        {
            return height;
        }
    private : 
        int width;
        int height;
};


int main() {
    my_space m;
    m.set_data(4,5); // setting the name of private members of the class
    cout<<m.get_width()<<endl;
    cout<<m.get_height()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

getting below output of the program

```
sh-4.3$ main                                                                                                                                                        
1544825248                                                                                                                                                          
32765
```

Comment: If you turn on your compiler warnings, it should tell you what's going on.

Answer (score 11):

The problem here is that `int width` and `int height` in function parameter list hide the `width` and `height` class member variables since the have the same name.  What your function does is assign the passed in values to themselves and then exist.  This means the `width` and `height` in the class are left uninitialized and they hold some unknown value.  What you need to do if you want the names to be the same is use the `this` pointer to diferentiate the names like

```
void set_data(int width,int height) // taking the same name of the variable as the class member functions
{
    this->width = width;
    this->height = height;
}
```

Now the compiler knows which is which.  You could also just name the function parameters to something else and then you would not need to use `this->`.

Also instead of having a set function you could use a constructor and initialize the object when you create it.  A constructor like

```
my_space(int width = 0, int height = 0) : width(width), height(height) {}
```

<sup>Here we can use the same names as the compiler knows which one is the member and which one is the parameter</sup>

Will always make sure the class is at least default constructed to a known state or you can provide your own values to make it a non-default state.